# org-mode export headlines levels only, not inline text

Tags: org-mode

I am trying to export headline levels only to an ODT file, without the inline text under each heading.

[Org file structure]

```
* Heading 1
  + Blah Blah
** Heading 1.1
   + Blah Blah
     - Blah Blah
* Heading 2
```

[Exported structure]

```
* Heading 1
** Heading 1.1
* Heading 2
```

Comment: Does adding something like +#OPTIONS: H:0 to the top of you file do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily cycle only through the headlines (S-tab) and then export with the option visible only. (C-v).

Comment: You should then accept it as the answer to your question.